# DNI show div based on landing page, continue showing div entire session

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, cookies, session-cookies

I have about 60 landing pages that use different phone numbers on them. I am using a combination of WordPress and Advanced Custom Fields to place the phone numbers on their respective pages.

I am being asked to show a `<div>` based on the landing page URL that will not only show the phone number assigned to that page, but, keep showing the `<div>`  (and phone number) regardless of what page the user navigates to on the website.

I have found little to no support on how to make the `<div>` remain visible throughout the entire session until the user closes the window.

I am thinking that this will somehow revolve around a cookie and Dynamic Number Insertion but I have no real progress to speak of. Should this be done using PHP or JS? Does a plugin exist that would allow for this on WordPress? I'm open to all suggestions.

Comment: have you had chance to check my code below?

Comment: Getting tested now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this code. Like @John C mentioned, WP Engine doesn't recommend Cookie nor PHP Session for the sake of performance and security. This is pure JavaScript code, and I think this will solve your problem.

Code in your Post/Page template file:

```
<div id="phone-number"></div>
<?php if( get_field('phone_number') ): ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        let phone_number = "<?php the_field('phone_number'); ?>";
    </script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Code in your theme JavaScript file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // in the case of the div data is persistent on the same site
    // let storage = localStorage;

    // in the case of the div data is persistent in the same tab, but not in new tab
    let storage = sessionStorage;
    
    let key = "phone_number"; // storage key

    var global_phone_number = storage.getItem(key);

    // check if storage data is set before
    if (null === global_phone_number) {
        // if not set the data on page into storage
        global_phone_number = phone_number ? phone_number : '';
        storage.setItem(key, global_phone_number);
    }
    document.getElementById('phone-number').innerHTML = global_phone_number;
</script>
```

Comment: So far so good. A few questions though. I need to grab my phone number inserted via Advanced Custom Fields and place that where the dynamic data is showing. I'm assuming I can just get rid of the Math.random but how to insert the phone number based on the ACF phone number entry? Or possible workaround? I'm not worried about the script carrying over tabbed browsing, as long as it's working on the same site in same window is fine.

Comment: Also, I only need the dynamic-data div loaded if the end user lands on a specific landing page. Using this method, even with private window is showing the div on every page.

Comment: I am also getting this Gulp error when I separate the two sets of scripts: ```GulpUglifyError: unable to minify JavaScript
Caused by: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: name «storage», expected: punc «;»
```

Comment: I updated my code with ACF `get_field()` function. If you can't fix the issue, DM me with your site detail, so that I can help you

Comment: Still getting JS error when separating into my site's JS file that is compiled using GULP. Still not producing any results except on the landing page itself. Does not carry over to other pages. Perhaps due to the JS error?

Comment: OK the only way I'm able to get any activity out of this is to put everything in ```footer.php```. Once I separate out the HTML into my custom page template -- the phone number will ONLY show on the custom page template and nowhere else. I need this to show up on every page once the landing page is touched. When I leave everything in the footer it "kind of" works but the ```<div id="phone-number"></div>``` is visible -- but empty -- on the start of a new session.

Comment: I guess you added style to `#phone-number` directly. You can wrap your text with another div and style the wrapper so that it isn't showing if `#phone-number` is empty. Alternate way is to delete the div with javascript if phone number is empty

Comment: I think the main problem you asked on this thread is solved and the remaining task is not related to this. So I think it would be good to discuss directly instead of commenting here. I sent you an email, and I can help you solve the remaining problems you have.

Answer (score 1):

You should use PHP and capture the session.

(untested code warning)

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'dynamic_phone_div');
function dynamic_phone_div() {
 session_start;

 if(isset($_SESSION['phone_div']) ? $phone_div = $_SESSION['phone_div'] : 
 $phone_div = '';

 if($phone_div != '') {

   echo '<div class="that_div_thing">';
   echo $phone_div;
   echo '</div>';

 } else {

   $_SESSION['phone_div'] = 123456789;
   echo '<div class="that_div_thing">';
   echo '123456789';
   echo '</div>';

 }
}
```

This is only raw logic. I am not sure where your div is (header/footer/page) - depending on where it is you should either use a hook (header/footer) or code it into a template (page/post).

The session will be destroyed after the user closes the tab/window.

Comment: The ```<div>``` will live in the footer physically but appear just as a fixed bottom div (similar to GDPR). Just put up a bounty as I'm looking for a more detailed answer.

Comment: Alright, so you need to use `wp_head` or `wp_footer` to insert the DIV and then just use CSS to position it. I edited my answer to insert it into the footer.

Comment: Relying on SESSION state is not always the best approach. It prevents the page from being cached on the server for instance and there have been security vulnerabilities.

As such, some hosters don't even support it (eg WPEngine).

Comment: Security vulnerabilities? We are not talking about user account or log in... It's a simple text to be displayed. And regarding the cache... you know that your below script will be cached too, right?

Comment: I'm using WP Engine in prod so -- I have to go with what will work there.

Comment: Unfortunately, WP Engine won't support PHP sessions. You need to disable their cache to make it work.

Comment: It can be done without using cookie nor session, so don't need to disable their cache. Please check my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do this with client side session storage. Providing all pages open in the same tab, the value will remain for the session, then be removed.

PHP code (in your functions.php file?) would be something like this:

```
function phone_script() {
    $params = array(
        'phone_number'      => null, // Insert logic for current number. Can stay null if this is running on a non-landing page
        'is_landing_page'   => false // Change to true/false based on is current page a landing one or not
    );

    $params = json_encode( $params );

    echo <<< EOT
    <script>
        let settings = $params;

        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
            if( settings.is_landing_page ) {
                window.sessionStorage.setItem( 'phone-number', settings.phone_number );
            } else {
                settings.phone_number = window.sessionStorage.getItem( 'phone-number' );
            }
            
            if( settings.phone_number ) {
                let div = document.createElement('div');
                div.classList.add('phone-div');
                // or add inline style 
                // div.style.cssText = 'position:fixed'; //etc

                // Some logic here to actually add the number and any other content to the div
                div.innerHTML = `The Phone number is: ${settings.phone_number}`;

                document.body.appendChild(div);
            }
        });
    </script>
EOT;
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'phone_script');
```

Note that the EOT; line MUST have no leading or trailing spaces.

The above is untested.

Comment: This ```echo <<< EOT;``` is causing a PHP error.

Comment: Sorry, it should read:

echo <<< EOT

And make sure the

EOT;

line further down has no spaces or tabs after it.